# Android SSL socket blocks on read while changing connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

I assume that when I do a read on the inputstream, it blocks until it gets more data to read.
I also assume that when the connection is closed, the read throws an IOException.

The problem is that sometimes when I change the connection from carrier to WiFi or from WiFi to carrier, the read just gets stuck and never throws the IOException.

The SDK is 1.5 and the phone a HTC Hero.

This behavior is quite ugly for me because I need to stay always connected.
Does someone else have ever seen this problem ? Is it a bug or am I the bug ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if a `Socket` ever remained viable after switching the underlying connection. This is likely to change the IP address, etc.

Comment: I agree with erikson, however I would expect it to throw some sort of exception instead of just hanging forever.

Comment: I agree with you, sometimes it sends an ioexception but sometimes it gets blocked in the read call.

Comment: And when I switch connection, the OutputStream "thinks" it is connected but it isn't (no IOExeption thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, sometimes it blocks even if I switch to plane mode. Streams attributes are : opened, not closed, bound, created.
Am I the only one to get this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly the same error (Nexus one, Android 2.1), using asmack which indeed does SSL. See link http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=16